# How to read password from Windows credentials?

Tags: passwords, windows, backup, decryption, credentials

What is the cipher used by windows Credential Manager to generate credentials backup files (*.crd)?

With a backup file from Credential Manager and the password used to created that backup file is it possible to decipher the file and read the stored credentials in plain text?

I have one password for a remote desktop that I forgot, but it is stored in the Credential Manager in my computer. I would like to read that password from my machine. Is there a way?

Comment: Not a bad question for pentest purposes. But for general "forgot password" purposes, you are probably better off just contacting the System Administrator for a reset or resetting it yourself locally with a boot disk.

Comment: I am "the administrator" : P

Comment: @Iszi does the boot disk would work? At the original machine or the machine with password in credential manager? And would use brute force?

Comment: Unless the system drive itself is encrypted, there's a number of boot disks that will allow you to change local account passwords for a Windows system. This would have to be done locally on the target system, not on an RDP client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Credential Manager stored passwords are managed by the [Data Protection API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) and protected by DPAPI "master keys":

> The DPAPI keys used for encrypting the user's RSA keys are stored
>   under %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Protect{SID} directory, where {SID} is the
>   Security Identifier of that user. The DPAPI key is stored in the same
>   file as the master key that protects the users private keys. It
>   usually is 64 bytes of random data.

[This Synactiv presentation](https://www.synacktiv.com/ressources/univershell_2017_dpapi.pdf) has a good overview of DPAPI master keys:

> These masterkeys are stored in blobs, each containing:
>
> - a GUID
> - a salt
> - master key structure (containing master keys)

... and includes this chart, which shows how the protections have changed with each release of Windows:

[image: chart of DPAPI algorithms by OS]

According to that presentation, shared keys can be extracted with [mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz). Beyond the Windows platform, the [dpapick](https://github.com/jordanbtucker/dpapick) project also supports offline and non-Windows use of the API, and both that project and John the Ripper include [DPAPImk2john.py](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/DPAPImk2john.py), a script for extracting the masterkey files for cracking purposes. [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) also supports cracking  these DPAPI v1 and v2 masterkey files with that script.

So you should be able to use DPAmk2john.py to extract the master keys, and then crack them to access the credentials.

Comment: Nice tools, but the easiest and smoothest way to read them on a "normally running and owned" live Windows system is [CredentialsFileView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/credentials_file_view.html) though imo.

Comment: CredentialsFileView solves a different problem: extracting credentials from "Credentials" files in the various locations documented on the NirSoft CredentialsFileView. That is different from DPAPI-based key storage, which is in a different part of the filesystem as documented above.