# Do Windows Credential Manager encrypt information stored in it?

Tags: encryption, windows

Apologize if this is a newbie question. Say the PC hard drive with Windows installed is un-encrypted (no BitLocker, etc); and someone gets physical access to the hard drive but does not know the (Windows) login. Can that person get information stored in WCM?

I am aware of this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119765/how-secure-is-the-windows-credential-manager) but (perhaps due to me being a newbie) seems to have not answered above question explicitly. The accepted answer says *it's secure at the user account level*, does that imply answer to my question is **NO**?

Answer (score 1):

> Can that person get information stored in WCM?

In theory, no. The data in WCM is encrypted using Windows DPAPI, which has a per-user encryption key that is itself encrypted using your login password. It's why resetting your password makes you lose access to that data. (The same DPAPI is also used to protect your certificates, such as the EFS per-user file encryption certificate.)

In practice, that person could dump the Windows account database to retrieve the hash of your login password and attempt to brute-force the password.

> does that imply answer to my question is NO?

No, it does not imply that.